# Magic Keyboard Home and End keys acts as Page Up and Page down

Tags: macos, keybindings

I'm using a Magic Keyboard with both my windows laptop and my Macbook Pro. When on MacOS, the Home and End keys default to Page Up and Page Down.

How do I remap the Home key to act as the Home button (moving the cursor to the beginning of a line) and similarly with the end key, moving the cursor to the end of the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Home doesn't move to the beginning of the line in macOS; that's a Windows thing.
On Mac Home is 'scroll to the top', End is 'scroll to the bottom', the cursor doesn't move.

Cmd/left or right arrow moves to the beginning & end of line.

As noted in comments, Microsoft have chosen to change the default behaviour for Word, to be more Windows-like, but this is not Mac-standard.

Comment: I have the full Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad, and the `home` &  `end` are right next to `page up` & `page down` keys, so there's no point having these keys function the way you've described @Tetsujin. Additionally, I've tested it on macOS Big Sur, and the `home` &  `end` keys work as the `Cmd`+`left`/`right` shortcut that moves the cursor to the start/end of a line. @Antares2018, I'm not sure what's going on with your Mac, but maybe check your `Keyboard` and `Accessibility` settings in `System Preferences.app`

Comment: **UPDATE:** Just did some research and it appears `home` & `end` keys **ONLY FUNCTION** in Mac's version of `Microsoft Word.app` as on Microsoft Windows. They **DO NOT FUNCTION** the same for other macOS Applications. You'll need to use the `Cmd`+`left`/`right` keyboard shortcut to move the cursor to the start/end of a line **FOR ALL OTHER** macOS applications

Comment: This answer is not addressing the question, and counter to the Stack Exchange guidelines.

Hopefully the 'official answer' tick can be removed from it? That would help everyone looking for the answer.

Comment: @OlegMihailik - Consider it a frame challenge. "Behave like the Home button" depends on your expectation of what that behaviour should be. The OP expected it to behave like Windows. It doesn't.

Comment: Totally, it's very useful as frame challenger — which is why it should not be marked as a correct answer.

Comment: @OlegMihailik - Neither you nor I are in charge of marking the answer correct or otherwise. That's entirely down to the OP. I still think you want someone to mind-read what you consider to be "correct behaviour". As far as I'm concerned, being a Mac user since 1989 & Win for a mere 20 years by comparison, the Mac version is 'correct' & the Windows one 'wrong'.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired behavior by installing keyboard modifications. One way to do this is to use Karabiner-Elements. Install "Home and End" from [here](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=home%20super%20arrow).